How to use this type as generic this<R> in TypeScript?
How to create a new generic collection of this type?
So, the Vector.map returns Vector<R> and SpecialisedVector.map returns SpecialisedVector<R>.
Example run it
class Vector<T> {
  items: T[]
  constructor(...items: T[]) { this.items = items }

  // This is the problem, how to create resulting 
  // collection of type `this<R>`?
  newInstance<R>(...items: R[]): any {
    return new (this.constructor as any)(...items)
  }

  map<R>(op: (v: T, i: number) => R) {
    return this.newInstance(...this.items.map(op))
  }
}

class SpecialisedVector<T> extends Vector<T> {
  sum(this: SpecialisedVector<number>): number {
    return this.items.reduce((a, b) => a + b)
  }
}

const v = new SpecialisedVector('a', 'b')
console.log(v.map((s) => s.length).sum()) // => 2


This isn't possible directly in TS without higher kinded types; see ms/TS#6223. You can try to work around it and encode HKTs or generic this type parameters, but all such methods are clunky in my opinion. Also note that this<R> doesn't even make sense if the subclass extends Vector<X> for some hardcoded X. This playground link is one possible approach for simulating HKTs, but it requires "registering" subclasses. Does that fully address the q? If so I'll write an a or find a duplicate; if not, what's missing?

@jcalz thanks, yes you answered it, I guess the answer is - no, it's not possible. The existing solutions are not good and can't be used.

This is not directly possible in TypeScript.  TypeScript currently lacks higher kinded types (HKTs) as requested in microsoft/TypeScript#1213, nor does it have the specific sort of higher kinded types that would allow you to give generic type parameters to the polymorphic this type, as requested in microsoft/TypeScript#6223. Until and unless either of those feature requests is implemented, you will either need to give up or work around it.
There are various workarounds to simulating higher kinded types in TypeScript, some of which are discussed in the GitHub issues linked above. One approach you can take is to make a "registry" of subclasses of Vector, which then lets you "apply" a new type argument to it. After each subclass is declared, you merge an entry into the registry interface (I've called it VectorTypes), like this:
class SpecialisedVector<T> extends Vector<T> {
  sum(this: SpecialisedVector<number>): number {
    return this.items.reduce((a, b) => a + b)
  }
}
interface VectorTypes<T> { specialisedVector: SpecialisedVector<T> } 

class AnotherVector<T> extends Vector<T> {
  sayHello() { console.log("hello") };
}
interface VectorTypes<T> { anotherVector: AnotherVector<T> } 

Something like this is currently necessary because you need to explain to TypeScript what this<T> means. Some subtypes of Vector might hardcode T, like class NumberVector extends Vector<number> {}, and then you can't possibly write this<string>, right? The VectorTypes<T> entry basically says: if you have a T, here's how you apply it to a particular subclass of Vector. Note that there couldn't be any reasonable entry for NumberVector, which resolves the issue neatly.  If TypeScript had higher kinded types you could probably just say "hey, any subclass of Vector needs to be generic in the way Vector is", but without it, you have to emulate it.
Anyway to Apply a vector subclass V with the type argument T you can write
type Apply<V, T> = {
  [K in keyof VectorTypes<any>]:
  V extends VectorTypes<any>[K] ? VectorTypes<T>[K] : never
}[keyof VectorTypes<any>]

which effectively looks up V in VectorTypes. And Vector's newInstance() would return
newInstance<R>(...items: R[]): Apply<this, R> {
  return new (this.constructor as any)(...items)
}

You can test out that it works:
const v = new SpecialisedVector('a', 'b');
const w = v.map(s => s.length);
//    ^? const w: SpecialisedVector<number>

console.log(v.map((s) => s.length).sum()) // => 2

const x = new AnotherVector(new Date());
//    ^? const x: AnotherVector<Date>
const y = x.map(d => d.getFullYear())
//    ^? const y: AnotherVector<number>

So it works, but at the expense of some manual registration. There are other ways to emulate higher kinded types, but in my opinion they are all clunky in some way, and so if you don't want to deal with that, then TypeScript currently lacks the features you need.  Of course most languages with generics also don't directly support higher kinded types, so it's not like TypeScript is uniquely deficient in this respect.
Playground link to code

To properly implement a type like This<T> that maintains the specific type of the current instance while parametrizing it with a new type argument, we can leverage TypeScript generics combined with polymorphic this types.
This is the modified code:
// Use `this` as a generic parameter to preserve type information.
type This<T> = { new <R>(...args: any[]): This<R> } & Vector<T>;

class Vector<T> {
  items: T[];

  constructor(...items: T[]) {
    this.items = items;
  }

  // This method preserves the type of `this`.
  newInstance<R>(...items: R[]): this & Vector<R> {
    // Use `this.constructor` to create a new instance of the same class.
    return new (this.constructor as any)(...items);
  }

  map<R>(op: (v: T, i: number) => R): this & Vector<R> {
    return this.newInstance(...this.items.map(op));
  }
}

class SpecialisedVector<T> extends Vector<T> {
  sum(this: SpecialisedVector<number>): number {
    return this.items.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
  }
}

// Example Usage
const v = new SpecialisedVector('a', 'b');

// Map string lengths to numbers and sum them up.
console.log(v.map((s) => s.length).sum()); // Output: 2


You don't want this & Vector<R>, that makes v.map(s => s.length) into a SpecialisedVector<string> & Vector<number>, so items is of type string[] & number[], which is not correct.
